# Assigning Repeating Indicators Using a Column in python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this pandas dataframe: `pd.DataFrame(['down', 'down', 'down', 'up', 'up', 'down', 'down', 'down', 'down', 'up', 'up', 'up'], columns = ['var'])`.

I want an indicator variable that will do something similar to ranking it but should allow duplications like this:

```
pd.DataFrame([['down', 0], ['down', 0], ['down', 0], ['up', 0], ['up', 0], ['down', 1], ['down', 1], ['down', 1], ['down', 1], ['up', 1], ['up', 1], ['up', 1]], columns = ['var', 'indicator'])
```

What would be the way to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `shift` and `cumsum`:

```
df['Indicator'] = (df['var'].eq('down') 
                   & df['var'].shift().eq('up')
                  ).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
     var  Indicator
0   down          0
1   down          0
2   down          0
3     up          0
4     up          0
5   down          1
6   down          1
7   down          1
8   down          1
9     up          1
10    up          1
11    up          1
```

Comment: Fantastic! This works perfect. What is this 'eq' doing in this code?

Comment: @KennethSingh `eq` stands for `equal`. `df['var'].eq('down')` is equivalent to `(df['var']=='down')`